# Why does naming convention of models differ from controllers, helpers, etc.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a rack based web framework on my own, and I got confused when I refer to the design of Ruby on Rails.

1. Why should a model in Rails be named like `User` instead of `UserModel`, just like controllers or helpers do (for example, `UsersController`, `PostsHelper`)?
2. If the naming convention of model is good, why don't controllers or helpers follow the same rule? The `Controller` and `Helper` postfix is bit tedious.
3. Is it good to namespace everything? For example: `Controller::User`, `Model::User`.
4. Are there any good references/books that talk about the file structure of software?

Answer (score 4):

I think that it's for convenience sake.  You would never usually reference the controller and helper classes in your code, whereas you reference the model classes all the time.  If they were called UserModel you would have lots of code like

```
user = UserModel.first
post = PostModel.first
```

there's two problems with this:  it breaks the convention of "call the instance variable name after the class", which is a simple bit of self-documentation, and also it's cumbersome, with a lot of repeated information.

Also, the User class does actually represent a real life user, whereas the UserController class doesn't represent anything in the real world, it's just part of the machinery, if you know what i mean.

EDIT - some more answers:

3) Namespacing should be reserved for separate sections of your site, like an admin section for example:  you can have an AdminController which inherits from ApplicationController, and adds a few more bits (such as a before_filter for checking that there's a current user and that they're an admin), and then your other admin section controllers inherit from AdminController.  Namespacing in the routes allows easy management of this.

4) As for books, read this:  http://www.amazon.co.uk/Agile-Development-Rails-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1937785564/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1450792683&sr=1-1&keywords=hansson+rails

It has some "Make a blog in 15 minutes" type stuff which i would actually recommend NOT diving into until you understand the underlying architecture, which is well explained elsewhere in the book.  Too many people dive into Rails without understanding what they are doing (their hapless questions fill this forum).

Answer (score 2):

All about convention, had to decide something. I don't speak for the rails core but this is my thoughts.

Model - In most cases, this is a representation of a single instance of a something.  Although you could have cases where that is not the case, it helps me to conceptualize the singularity of it.  I.e.  I am dealing with a User not a Users

Controller/Helpers/Tablenames - In the database a User model maps to users table.  The controller and helpers follow the same convention of the database.

Namespacing is good, but you should only namespace something when it makes sense on a clear boundary.

A great ruby framework to look at that is not rails is Lotus - http://lotusrb.org/  It uses namespaces heavily.